# Testing Upgradeability fails with UUPS

Tags: ethers.js, solidity-0.8.x, hardhat-deploy, contract-upgrading

Thank you in advance for helping me out with the blockage I'm facing here. I deployed an upgradeable contract, all tests went well except when I tested upgradeability.

the contract is access control, ERC1155, & UUPS based as follows:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: unlicesned
pragma solidity >=0.8.10 <0.9.0;

import '@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/token/ERC1155/ERC1155Upgradeable.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/AccessControlUpgradeable.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/UUPSUpgradeable.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/utils/AddressUpgradeable.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/security/PausableUpgradeable.sol';
import '@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/security/ReentrancyGuardUpgradeable.sol';



// solhint-disable-next-line contract-name-camelcase
contract IDToken is 
    Initializable, 
    ERC1155Upgradeable, 
    AccessControlUpgradeable, 
    UUPSUpgradeable, 
    PausableUpgradeable, 
    ReentrancyGuardUpgradeable 
{

    using AddressUpgradeable for address;


    /**
     * constant varaibles - non storage variables
     */
    bytes32 private constant UPGRADER_ROLE = keccak256(abi.encodePacked('UPGRADER_ROLE'));
    bytes32 private constant MINTER_ROLE = keccak256(abi.encodePacked('MINTER_ROLE'));
    bytes32 private constant MANAGER_ROLE = keccak256(abi.encodePacked('MANAGER_ROLE'));


    modifier notZeroAddress(address addr) {
        if(addr == address(0))
            revert IDToken_ZeroAddress();
        _;
    }
    

    // solhint-disable-next-line func-name-mixedcase
    function __IDToken_init
    (
        address upgrader, 
        address manager, 
        string memory uri_
    ) 
    public 
    initializer 
    virtual 
    override 
    notZeroAddress(_msgSender())
    notZeroAddress(upgrader)
    notZeroAddress(manager)
    {

        __ERC1155_init(uri_);
        __AccessControl_init();
        __UUPSUpgradeable_init();
        __Pausable_init();

        _setupRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, _msgSender());
        _setupRole(UPGRADER_ROLE, upgrader);
        _setupRole(MANAGER_ROLE, manager);
    }


    function _authorizeUpgrade(address newImplementation) internal virtual override onlyRole(UPGRADER_ROLE) whenPaused notZeroAddress(newImplementation) {
        require(AddressUpgradeable.isContract(newImplementation), 'new implementation not contract');
    }
}
```

## Using hardhat-deploy

```
const { ethers, network } = require('hardhat')

const DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE = ethers.constants.HashZero

const UPGRADER_ROLE = ethers.utils.id('UPGRADER_ROLE')   

const MANAGER_ROLE = ethers.utils.id('MANAGER_ROLE')

const MINTER_ROLE = ethers.utils.id('MINTER_ROLE')

const addressZero = ethers.constants.AddressZero

module.exports = async({getNamedAccounts, deployments}) => {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments;
    const { admin, upgrader, manager } = await getNamedAccounts();
    console.log({namedAccounts: await getNamedAccounts()})
    const networkName = network.name
 
    log(`-----Preparing Contracts for Deployment on ${networkName} -------`)

    const idContract = await deploy('IDToken', {
        contract: 'IDToken',
        from: admin,
        args:[],
        log: true,
        proxy: {
            proxyContract: 'UUPS',
            execute: {
                methodName: '__IDToken_init',
                args: [
                    upgrader, 
                    manager,
                    'http://bafybeihqp5dcnhnspwhs3fqh4tmzweu6nw33iukx6i4sqnv4vwed3zuwc4.ipfs.localhost:8080/{id}.json'
                ]
            }

        },
        waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1
    })
    const IDToken = await ethers.getContractFactory('IDToken', admin)
    const idToken = await IDToken.attach(idContract.address)
    log(`01- IDToken Proxy deployed at: ${idToken.address}`)
   
    await idToken.grantRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, admin)
    
    const checkAdmin = await idToken.hasRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, admin)
    const checkUpgrader = await idToken.hasRole(UPGRADER_ROLE, upgrader)
    const checkManager = await idToken.hasRole(MANAGER_ROLE, manager)
 
    console.log(`Does ${admin} has admin role? ${checkAdmin}`)
    console.log(`Does ${upgrader} has upgrader role? ${checkUpgrader}`)
    console.log(`Does ${manager} has manager role? ${checkManager}`)
    

}
module.exports.tags = ['all', 'ids']
```

The above deploy scripts run well with no errors, now when I try to test upgradeability by calling `upgradeTo(address newImplementation)` function on the IDToken Proxy contract it reverted with Error
`reverted with reason string 'AccessControl: account 0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266 is missing role 0x189ab7a9244df0848122154315af71fe140f3db0fe014031783b0946b8c9d2e3'`

which is basically reading the tx signer as the admin account and that's why it's missing `UPGRADER_ROLE` even though I'm using the upgrader account to sign the upgrade function!!

#### Upgrading deploy Script as follows:

```
const { ethers } = require('hardhat')

module.exports = async({getNamedAccounts, deployments}) => {
    const { deploy } = deployments;
    const { upgrader, admin } = await getNamedAccounts();
    console.log({namedAccounts: await getNamedAccounts()})


    const implV2 = await deploy('IDTokenV2', {
        contract: 'IDTokenV2',
        from: upgrader,
        args:[],
        log: true,
        waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmations || 1
    })
    
    const implementationV2 = await ethers.getContractAt('IDTokenV2', implV2.address)

    const idToken = await ethers.getContract('IDToken', admin)

    console.log(`IDTokenV2 Implementation address is ${implementationV2.address}`)

    await idToken.connect(upgrader)

    const secondVersion = await idToken.upgradeTo(implementationV2.address)
    
  

}
module.exports.tags = ['implV2']
```

#### and the upgraded contract:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.8.10 <0.9.0;

import '../IDToken.sol';


contract IDTokenV2 is IDToken {

    function version() public pure virtual override returns(string memory) {
        return '2.0.0';
    }

}
```

stuck for 5 hours and hit the gym twice and still can't figure it out!!!